# How to modify a UIPickerView's selected Cell?

Tags: ios

I have a UIPickerView with three components for meters , centimeters and millimeters and I want to be able to modify the selected cell such that.

say If I select, 10,20, 5 for m,cm and mm.

I should  be able to display these units besides the numbers in the selected cell as 10m 20cm 5mm.

How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution but seems to be working...

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:     (NSInteger)component
{
    UILabel *tempView1 = (UILabel *)[pickerView viewForRow:lastSelectedRow  forComponent:lastSelectedComponent];
    tView1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[yourDataArray objectAtIndex:lastSelectedRow]];

    UILabel *tView = (UILabel *)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
    tView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ cm",[yourDataArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    lastSelectedRow = row;
    lastSelectedComponent = component;

}
```

Here i have lastSelectedRow and lastSelectedComponent as my class variables.

Comment: That was the only thing in my mind. I thought there must be some other way but anyways thanks.